# How is log_softmax() implemented to compute its value (and gradient) with better speed and numerical stability?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, numerical-methods, mxnet

Both MXNet and PyTorch provide special implementation for computing log(softmax()), which is faster and numerically more stable. However, I cannot find the actual Python implementation for this function, log_softmax(), in either package.

Can anyone explain how this is implemented, or better, point me to the relevant source code?

Comment: Here is all you need: https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/

Comment: These aren't implemented in Python but a compiled language. Did you look just for Python code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- The numerical error:

```py
>>> x = np.array([1, -10, 1000])
>>> np.exp(x) / np.exp(x).sum()
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
Out[4]: array([ 0.,  0., nan])
```

There are 2 methods to avoid the numerical error while compute the softmax:

- Exp Normalization:

[image]

```py
def exp_normalize(x):
    b = x.max()
    y = np.exp(x - b)
    return y / y.sum()

>>> exp_normalize(x)
array([0., 0., 1.])
```

- Log Sum Exp

[image]

```py
def log_softmax(x):
    c = x.max()
    logsumexp = np.log(np.exp(x - c).sum())
    return x - c - logsumexp
```

Please note that, a reasonable choice for both b, c in above formula is max(x). With this choice, overflow due to exp is impossible. The largest number exponentiated after shifting is 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can find one of the CPU implementations [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/bcb0bb7e0e03b386ad837015faba6b4b16e3bfb9/aten/src/ATen/native/SoftMax.cpp#L14-L64) and a vectorized version [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5baa6b6c34c9a61c936f90168b6449421814553d/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/SoftMaxKernel.cpp#L25-L93) (this is the log version, called from [`vec_host_softmax_lastdim`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5baa6b6c34c9a61c936f90168b6449421814553d/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/SoftMaxKernel.cpp#L187-L204) ).

You can find a CUDA implementation [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5baa6b6c34c9a61c936f90168b6449421814553d/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/SoftMax.cu#L488-L573), which then calls [`softmax_warp_forward`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5baa6b6c34c9a61c936f90168b6449421814553d/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/PersistentSoftmax.cuh#L46-L153).

They are all similar, just the syntax that differs. As you can see, there is usually a flag that defines whether or not softmax will be computed using the log., i.e., LogSoftMax instead of SoftMax.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the actual C++ implementation, which uses the same trick as what described in Jonny Vu's answer.

Comment: @herrlich10 yeah, as I said, they are all identical, syntax is the only thing that differs. I thought you knew the trick and was just looking for the source-code :) I would've explained the trick as well.