# Is there a reason some (all?) libraries don't implement log_softmax via log1p(x) = log(1 + x)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, numerical-methods

As I understand it, PyTorch implements `log_softmax(x)` as `x - x.max() - (x - x.max()).exp().sum().log()`, for added numerical stability.  (See, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568783/377022).)  However, when the largest value is much larger than the rest of the values (about 16 larger for float32, about 36 larger for float64), `log_softmax` returns `0` at the maximum value, when it could give a much more precise answer.

Numerically, we have

```py
>>> eps = torch.tensor(torch.finfo(torch.float32).eps)
>>> -torch.tensor([1-(2*eps).log(), 0]).log_softmax(dim=0)
tensor([1.1921e-07, 1.6249e+01])
>>> -torch.tensor([1-eps.log(), 0]).log_softmax(dim=0)
tensor([-0.0000, 16.9424])
```

(For float16, this is 7.2e-4.)

As I understand it, `log` and `exp` are implemented under the hood using some sort of polynomial(?) series expansion.  (cf, eg, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519989/377022))  1.19e-7 is the unit of least precision for float32 around 1, but float32 can represent values as small as about 1.18e-38 normally (`torch.finfo(torch.float32).smallest_normal`, `2**-126 = 2**-(2**7 - 2)`) or about 1.18e-45 (`2**-126 * 2**-23`) subnormally.  So there's a lot of room for more precision, which could be achieved by having functions like `expm1(x)` which is `exp(x) - 1` but with more precision, and `log1p(x)` which is `log(1 + x)` but with more precision on tiny values of `x`.  Then we could implement `log_softmax(x)` as

```py
maxi = x.argmax()
xoffset = x - x[maxi]
xoffsetexp = xoffset.exp()
# xoffsetexp[maxi] is currently about 1
xoffsetexp[maxi] = 0
xoffsetexp_sum_m1 = xoffsetexp.sum()
return xoffset - xoffsetexp_sum_m1.log1p()
```

This might, for example, allow model training to not be dominated by floating point errors quite as early, in some cases.

**Do any libraries implement `log_softmax` this way?  Are there reasons to avoid implementing `log_softmax` this way?**

Comment: _"Is there any discussion..."_ - not on [so]. This is a Q&A site. _"Do any libraries..."_ falls under recommendation requests, which is specifically off topic here.

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation request, I'm asking for knowledge of the existing state of the art.  I've changed "Is there any discussion..." to "Are there reasons to avoid implementing `log_softmax` this way?". I'm looking for responses like "Yes, this is a common implementation pattern, it's just pytorch that doesn't do it" or "This textbook/article/whatever gives such-and-such reasons why implementing `log_softmax` this way is a bad idea" or "There's folkwisdom that this is an optimization for a corner-case that doesn't matter" or "Probably it's just that nobody thought of this before"

Comment: I think it is a fair question to ask when a more numerically accurate alternative is available but isn't used in a particular library. I can't answer the OP's question. The only reason I can think of is that perhaps they found that truncating to zero early actually works better in practice that propagating tiny values forwards. Worth trying it out to see if there is any improvement in performance with the suggested alternative.